# There are $2^n$ tickets in a jar.The frequency of the tickets of number $i$ is ${n \choose i}$

Tags: probability

There are $2^n$ tickets in a jar.The frequency of the tickets of number $i$ is ${n \choose i}$ where $i=0,1,2,..n$.

$m$ tickets are drawn randomly without replacement.

Let S be the sum of the numbers drawn.Find $E(S)$ and variance of S.

I can't find a way to approach this problem.

Comment: Is the drawing with or without replacement?

Comment: Without replacement

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2813390/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without resorting to generating functions we can do the following:

Let $X_i$ denote the number on the $i$th ticket for $i=1,2,...,m$, so that $S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^mX_i$.

The pmf of $X_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,m$ is then $$P(X_i=k)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{k}&,\text{ if } k=0,1,\ldots,n\\\\\quad0&,\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Since $\operatorname{E}(X_i)=\frac{n}{2}$, it follows that $$\operatorname{E}(S)=\frac{mn}{2}$$

Again $\operatorname{E}(X_i^2)=\frac{n(n+1)}{4}$, giving $$\operatorname{Var}(X_i)=\operatorname{E}(X_i^2)-(\operatorname{E}(X_i))^2=\frac{n}{4}$$

The calculation of variance of $S$ is a bit more involved.

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(S)&=\sum_{i=1}^m\operatorname{Var}(X_i)+2\sum_{i<j}\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)
\\&=m\cdot\frac{n}{4}+2\binom{m}{2}\rho\cdot\frac{n}{4}\qquad,\small\rho\text{ is the correlation  between $X_i$ and $X_j$}
\\&=\frac{mn}{4}\left(1+(m-1)\rho\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}

Now observe that $$\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\color\green{2^n}}X_i\right)=0\tag{2}$$, the sum within parentheses being a constant.

Moreover the joint distribution of $(X_i,X_j)$ for all $i\ne j$ is independent of $m$.

So we can replace $m$ by $2^n$ in $(1)$ to get from $(2)$:

$$\frac{n2^n}{4}(1+(2^n-1)\rho)=0$$

That is, $$\rho=\frac{1}{1-2^n}$$

Substituting the value of $\rho$ in $(1)$, we get $$\operatorname{Var}(S)=\frac{mn}{4}\left(1+\frac{m-1}{1-2^n}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

This problem is  a type of coupon collector  without replacement where
there are  ${n\choose j}$  tickets of  type $j$ and  we ask  about the
expectation of  the sum of  the ticket  values after $m$  tickets have
been  drawn.  Using  the  methodology  from  the  following  two  [MSE
links](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348811/) we find that
the EGF by multiplicity of a set of coupons of type $j$ is given by

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n\choose j} 
{n\choose j}^{\underline{k}} \frac{z^k}{k!} =
(1+z)^{n\choose j}.$$

Distributing all $n$ types of coupons we get

$$\prod_{j=0}^n (1+z)^{n\choose j}
= (1+z)^{2^n}$$

for a total count according to multiplicity of

$$m! [z^m] (1+z)^{2^n} = m! \times {2^n\choose m}.$$

Marking the contribution of a ticket  of type $j$ with $u^j$ we obtain
the mixed generating function

$$G(z, u) = \prod_{j=0}^n (1+u^j z)^{n\choose j}.$$

Differentiate and evaluate at $u=1$ to obtain

$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u)\right|_{u=1}
\\ = \left. \prod_{j=0}^n (1+u^j z)^{n\choose j}
\sum_{j=0}^n (1+u^j z)^{-{n\choose j}} 
{n\choose j} (1+u^j z)^{{n\choose j}-1}
j u^{j-1} z \right|_{u=1}
\\ = (1+z)^{2^n} 
\sum_{j=1}^n {n\choose j} \frac{jz}{1+z}
= z (1+z)^{2^n-1} \sum_{j=1}^n j {n\choose j}
\\ = z (1+z)^{2^n-1} \sum_{j=1}^n n {n-1\choose j-1}
= n 2^{n-1} z (1+z)^{2^n-1}.$$

Extracting coefficients we thus obtain for the expectation of the sum

$$\mathrm{E}[S] = {2^n\choose m}^{-1} n 2^{n-1} {2^n-1\choose m-1}
= n 2^{n-1} \frac{m}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2} nm.$$

Continuing with the variance we evidently require the second factorial
moment. Differentiating twice we get three components, the first is

$$\left. \prod_{j=0}^n (1+u^j z)^{n\choose j}
\sum_{j=0}^n (1+u^j z)^{-{n\choose j}} 
{n\choose j} (1+u^j z)^{{n\choose j}-1}
j(j-1) u^{j-2} z \right|_{u=1}
\\ = z (1+z)^{2^n-1} \sum_{j=2}^n j(j-1) {n\choose j}
\\ = z (1+z)^{2^n-1} \sum_{j=2}^n n(n-1) {n-2\choose j-2}
= n(n-1) 2^{n-2} z (1+z)^{2^n-1}.$$

The second is

$$\left. \prod_{j=0}^n (1+u^j z)^{n\choose j}
\sum_{j=0}^n (1+u^j z)^{-{n\choose j}} 
{n\choose j} \left({n\choose j}-1\right) (1+u^j z)^{{n\choose j}-2}
j^2 u^{2j-2} z^2 \right|_{u=1}
\\ = z^2 (1+z)^{2^n-2} \sum_{j=1}^n j^2
{n\choose j} \left({n\choose j}-1\right).$$

The third is

$$\left. 2\prod_{j=0}^n (1+u^j z)^{n\choose j}
\sum_{j=0}^n (1+u^j z)^{-{n\choose j}} 
{n\choose j} (1+u^j z)^{{n\choose j}-1}
j u^{j-1} z 
\\ \times 
\sum_{k=j+1}^n (1+u^k z)^{-{n\choose k}} 
{n\choose k} (1+u^k z)^{{n\choose k}-1}
k u^{k-1} z 
\right|_{u=1}
\\ = 2 z^2 (1+z)^{2^n-2} \sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} j
\sum_{k=j+1}^n {n\choose k} k.$$

The coefficients on these last two may be joined and we get

$$-\sum_{j=1}^n j^2 {n\choose j}
+ \left(\sum_{j=1}^n j {n\choose j} \right)^2
\\ = -\sum_{j=1}^n j(j-1) {n\choose j} - \sum_{j=1}^n j {n\choose j}
+ \left(n \sum_{j=1}^n {n-1\choose j-1} \right)^2
\\ = - n(n-1)\sum_{j=2}^n  {n-2\choose j-2} - n \sum_{j=1}^n {n-1\choose j-1}
+ n^2 2^{2n-2}
\\ = - n(n-1) 2^{n-2} - n 2^{n-1} + n^2 2^{2n-2}
= n^2 2^{2n-2} - n(n+1) 2^{n-2}.$$

Extracting coefficients we get for the second factorial moment

$$\frac{1}{4} n(n-1)m 
+ (n^2 2^{2n-2} - n(n+1) 2^{n-2}) \frac{m(m-1)}{2^n(2^n-1)}$$

or alternatively

$$\mathrm{E}[S(S-1)] =
\frac{1}{4} n(n-1)m  + \frac{1}{4} \frac{m(m-1)}{2^n-1}
(n^2 2^{n} - n(n+1)).$$

Finally recall that

$$\mathrm{Var}[S] = \mathrm{E}[S(S-1)] + \mathrm{E}[S] - \mathrm{E}[S]^2$$

so the answer to the problem posed by the OP is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[S] = \frac{1}{2} nm}$$

and

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{Var}[S] = 
\frac{1}{4} n(n+1)m  + \frac{1}{4} \frac{m(m-1)}{2^n-1}
(n^2 2^{n} - n(n+1))
- \frac{1}{4} n^2 m^2.}$$

As a sanity check when $m=2^n$ and all coupons have been drawn we have
deterministically that

$$\mathrm{E}[S] = \sum_{j=0}^n j {n\choose j} 
= n \sum_{j=1}^n {n-1\choose j-1} = n 2^{n-1} = \frac{1}{2} n m$$

and the check goes through.

With  this  problem  requiring  careful  algebra  I  also  coded  a
simulation of the coupon collector that  is featured here which was in
**excellent** agreement on all values  that were tested (outputs first
and second  factorial moment).  Some optimizations  are still possible
which is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int n = 4 , m = 2, trials = 1000; 

  if(argc >= 2){
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
  }

  if(argc >= 3){
    m = atoi(argv[2]);
  }

  if(argc >= 4){
    trials = atoi(argv[3]);
  }

  assert(1 <= n);
  assert(1 <= m && m <= 1 << n);
  assert(1 <= trials);

  int all = 1 << n;
  int bincfs[n+1];

  bincfs[0] = 1;
  for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    bincfs[k] = bincfs[k-1]*(n+1-k)/k;

  srand48(time(NULL));
  long long data = 0, dataV = 0;

  for(int tind = 0; tind < trials; tind++){
    int src[1 << n];

    int srcpos = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k <= n; k++)
      for(int r = 0; r < bincfs[k]; r++)
        src[srcpos++] = k;

    int steps = 0; int sum = 0;

    while(steps < m){
      int cpidx = drand48() * (double)(all-steps);
      int coupon = src[cpidx];

      for(int cind=cpidx; cind < all-steps-1; cind++)
        src[cind] = src[cind+1];

      steps++;
      sum += coupon;
    }

    data += sum;
    dataV += sum*(sum-1);
  }

  long double
    fm1 = (long double)data/(long double)trials,
    fm2 = (long double)dataV/(long double)trials;

  printf("[n = %d, m = %d, trials = %d]: %Le, %Le\n", 
         n, m, trials, fm1, fm2);

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Congratulation on this very complete and useful answer =)

Comment: Thank you for the kind remark, it was a somewhat unusual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the expectation of the value of one ticket?  Now use the linearity of expectation.  Can you find the variance of the value of one ticket?  Look up the definition.  What is the variance of a sum?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily deduce that, with $X$ the ticket number variable : $$\forall i \in [0,n], P(X = i) = {{n\choose i}\over 2^n}$$

From there, you can apply the formula for expectation :

$$E(X) = \sum_{i=0}^n P(X=i)\cdot i=\sum_{i=0}^n {{n\choose i}\over 2^n}\cdot i$$

Then the formula for variance :

$$V(X) = E[(X-E(X))^2]$$

Comment: Since tickets are not replaced, this is expectation for the value of the first ticket only?

Comment: You're absolutely right @dEmigOd, and since the probability isn't equiprobable we can't just say $E(S)=m\cdot E(X)$.

Looks like I missed the point of the author's post :/

Comment: If $X_i$ denotes the number appearing on the $i$th ticket $(i=1,2,...,m)$, then sum of the numbers on the tickets drawn is $X=\sum_{i=1}^mX_i$. The probability distribution of $X_i$ is precisely what you have stated,i.e., $P(X_i=k)=\frac{1}{2^n}{\binom{n}{k}}$ for $k=0,1,...,n$. So the problem can be definitely solved using this.

Comment: My computation is right for the first draw but since it's without replacement and the tickets are not equiprobables I don't think we can conclude.